# Why isn't npm start not building and connecting to the dev server?

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to work my way through a React course and I am consistently running into the same issue. Every time I use npm start after I've created the app I get this error in the browser: This site can’t be reached. Localhost took too long to respond or I get the error that it refused to connect.

Here's everything I've tried to remedy the issue:

- I'm not getting any errors in VScode's built in terminal or my laptop's terminal, it says everything compiled successfully.
- I've tried opening the dev server on multiple different browsers: Brave, Chrome, Firefox.
- I've created multiple different projects & all are having the same issue.
- I've changed the port the dev server opens up on in VScode.
- I've cleared my node cache.
- I've uninstalled & reinstalled node & npm.
- I've restarted my laptop multiple times
- I've uninstalled & reinstalled VScode.
- I even went so far as to completely factory reset my laptop & reinstall everything. It fixed the problem for a couple of days but now I'm back at square one dealing with the same issue.

My laptop is a 2017 MBP 13 running macOS Monterey. Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

````
curl -v "http://localhost:3000"
 Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
*   Trying ::1:3000...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 25918 ms: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 25918 ms: Operation timed out
```
````

Comment: Can u show your code to us ? like `index.jsx` or `App.jsx` stuff

Comment: Just added screenshots of index.js & app.js

Comment: So you're opening `http://localhost:3002` in your browser? Can you try `curl` from the terminal and see what it says?... `curl -v "http://localhost:3002"`

Comment: @Phil it returns: trying to connect to port 3002 failed: connection refused & then repeats the same line followed by operation timed out, closing connection.

Comment: Are you making sure where you ran `npm start` is still running? Ie, you run `npm start` in one terminal and then `curl` in another

Comment: @Phil, npm start is still running in one terminal & I typed the curl command in another terminal window. I've done it twice & received the same response both times.

Comment: @Phil I just uploaded a screenshot showing the curl output in the terminal.

Comment: @Phil, sorry. I removed the screenshots & threw everything in the terminal running the curl command in a code block.

Comment: Really not sure what else to try. I just created a new react app via `npx create-react-app react-test` then changed into the directory with `cd react-test` and ran `npm start`. Got the same compilation _success_ message as you and it opened `http://localhost:3000` in the browser just fine. Perhaps check your Firewall options in _Security & Privacy_.

Comment: @Phil my firewall is off, it's set to allow all incoming connections. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. I had to turn off my VPN for the npm start command to work.

Comment: you can mark this as the final answer